# CSS Re-size page automatically once page is adjusted

Tags: html, css

Good day all. how can i set my CSS in a way that each time i re-size my browser, the content on the page will automatic be re-size accordingly.

Comment: Try searching for responsive web designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the sample code.. have a look

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Strawberries</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function image(url, width, height) {
            return('<IMG SRC="' + url + '"' +
                ' WIDTH=' + width +
                ' HEIGHT=' + height + '>');
        }
        function strawberry1(width) {
            return(image("images/Strawberry1.gif", width, Math.round(width*1.323)));
        }

        function strawberry2(width) {
            return(image("images/Strawberry2.gif", width, Math.round(width*1.155)));
        }
        // -->
    </SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var imageWidth = window.innerWidth/4;
        var fontSize = Math.min(7, Math.round(window.innerWidth/100));
        document.writeln('<TABLE>\n' +' <TR><TD>' + strawberry1(imageWidth) + '\n' +'<TH><FONT SIZE=' + fontSize + '>\n' +'"Doubtless God <I>could</I> have made\n' +'a better berry, but doubtless He\n' +'never did."</FONT>\n'+'<TD>' + strawberry2(imageWidth) + '\n' +'</TABLE>');
        // -->
    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>    
<HR>

Strawberries are my favorite garden crop; a fresh ...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use
`%` instead of `px`.
You can also use javascript

Comment: How can i use java-script to achieve this? will be glad if you can help out with example. thanks

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add the weight and complexity of js to solve such a simple problem. CSS is lighter and an easier to implement fix.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is a responsive framework. I suggest you used an existing  one like [Foundation 3](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). They also offer more than just being responsive such as pre-styled buttons, accordion menus, dropdown menus and lots more.